# FLTFirebaseAuth: An error occurred while calling method Auth#signInWithCredential, errorOrNil => (null)

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

FLTFirebaseAuth: An error occurred while calling method Auth#signInWithCredential, errorOrNil => (null)

just it 2023-06-25 14:26:35.205463+0300 Runner[773:2535475] [connection] nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal_block_invoke [C111] Client called nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal on unconnected nw_connection
2023-06-25 14:26:35.679790+0300 Runner[773:2534769] flutter: {name: Nadeem Abu Al Arayes, first_name: Nadeem, last_name: Abu Al Arayes, email: nadeemabualarayes@gmail.com, picture: {data: {height: 200, is_silhouette: false, url: https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=2599167620229897&height=200&ext=1690284395&hash=AeTCaa6sCvd8K5x9E0o, width: 200}}, id: 2599167620229897}
2023-06-25 14:26:35.680249+0300 Runner[773:2534769] flutter: nadeemabualarayes@gmail.com
2023-06-25 14:26:35.680529+0300 Runner[773:2534769] flutter: nadeemabualarayes@gmail.com
2023-06-25 14:26:35.680836+0300 Runner[773:2534769] flutter: ----------------------